# Ruby/Rails DateTime.utc.iso8601 and Time.utc.iso8601 format differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, timezone-offset

Since Rails monkeypatches the date objects, it's not clear to me if this is a Rails specific behavior or a Ruby specific behavior.

```
DateTime.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2018-02-20T06:31:44+00:00"

Time.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2018-02-20T06:31:44Z"
```

Note how one has the timezone string "+00:00" and the other has the string "Z". They're both equivalent in the iso8610 standard, but I'm trying to produce the same string given either starting class type.

[The Ruby docs on Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) don't even document the `#iso8601` method, they just show it in use in a different context, so I'm not sure how to figure out what's going on.

Comment: There's `Time` in the core and then there's the extra stuff from the standard library that gets patched into `Time` when you `require 'time'`, that's where you'll find `Time#iso8601` (which is just an alias for `Time#xmlschema`): http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html

Comment: On my system both return `Z`. What version of Ruby and Rails are you running?

Comment: I'm running ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 3.2. Upgrading is not an option for this specific case unfortunately. I'm asking how to get both to format in identical strings

Comment: Note their not *exactly* the same.  Both have a +0 offset, but `Z` explicitly means UTC while `+00:00` *may* have come from UTC, or may have come from a local time that happens to be using a +0 offset at the timestamp given.

Comment: @MattJohnson that is something I didn't consider! That may be a crucial piece of info here